# If $v$ is a vector in vector space $U$, then will $(-1)v$ be equal to the negative of $v$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

If $v$ is a vector in vector space $U$, then will $(-1)v$ be equal to the negative of $v$? I am learning about vectors and I might be overthinking this concept.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will.

If I define a vector $\vec{v}$ as
$$\vec{v}=\langle v_x,v_y,v_z\rangle$$
and then [multiply it by some scalar $c$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_multiplication), I then get
$$c\cdot\vec{v}=\langle cv_x,cv_y,cv_z\rangle$$
If $c=-1$, I have
$$(-1)\vec{v}=\langle-v_x,-v_y,-v_z\rangle$$
I've just used $_x$,$_y$ and $_z$ to denote components of the vector. I've just chosen the familiar three-dimensional Cartesian system for simplicity, but it works for all cases.

Answer (score 1):

Yes!
The condition you have to check is:  Does $(-1)v + v = 0$?  And the answer is, yes, because $(-1)v + v = (-1 + 1)v = 0v = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

$0v=0\implies (-1 +1)v=0\implies (-1)v + v=0\implies (-1)v=-v$